# Define Variable with Pattern from String

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to find all the text that matches a pattern inside a very long string and then take the the text and apply it to a variable that will be passed on and so forth. I tried the `replaceAll` method but I started getting weird behaviour when passing on the `$1` to another method. Is there an alternative way to do this or am I doing something wrong?

`text = string.replaceAll("(PART)", "$1");`

Comment: Some of the relevant code please.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Show us the code.

Comment: `i started getting weird behaviour` --> [am I a guru?](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/The_Guru_Myth) You'll have to explain or show us the errors you are getting, what your input is, which output you expect, and what it is.

Comment: The problem is that the method that receives the `$1` seems to take it as exactly that `"$1"`. I've tried `"$1".toString()` among many other things. I know that `$1` is correct though because if I pass it to the method and make the method return back what it got then it returns the text matching the pattern. It's just that when I print out what it received in the method then it prints out `$1` literally.

Comment: there is no `$1` in the code you show us. We need that part to see if you do it correct. `"$1".toString()` clearly is _$1_

Answer (score 0):

[`String.replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) receives a regular expression as first parameter.

You might want to try [`String.replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29), as you can pass a "normal" string to be replaced.